# ubuntu 22.04 cannot connect to known wifi

Tags: wireless, 22.04

/var/log/syslog:
Connection is not available on device wlan0 because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)

Comment: Did your wifi have a different interface name?  There is a way to only use one interface for a connection in Network Manager settings

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to solve this, but found trick to fix

Settings -> WiFi -> Known Wifi Networks
Select your connection and "Forget"

In my case after connection been forgotten I could connect successfully

PS: I got this error regularly, so I posted this question-answer first of all for myself